# How to configure Terraform Kubernetes provider for EKS

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to configure the kubernetes provider in Terraform, however I've been unable to do it so far. EKS uses heptio authenticator, so I don't have certificate paths I can provide to the Kubernetes provider. What is the right way to accomplish this?

I already tried something like this:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_context_auth_info = "context1"
  config_context_cluster   = "kubernetes"
}
```

Getting as a result:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* kubernetes_namespace.example: 1 error(s) occurred:

* kubernetes_namespace.example: Post http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp [::1]:80: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I have a ~/.kube/config in place, what could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Such behaviour could be caused by known core bug: [core: No interpolation for cross-provider dependencies #12393](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12393).

There is an issue on the Terraform Github that describes a similar case with the same error - [#12869](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12869#issuecomment-288339585).
It is about issues related to GKE, but I guess it could affect EKS also.

Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/radeksimko/1a2cc98c5536bd4aa92e960ed7a47cf0) to gist with an example of using kubernetes_provider.
It also related to GKE, but I believe with slight changes it could be applied to EKS.

Consider also checking another good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50104891/9521610) on StackOverflow related to your question.
In brief, the solution is to create Kubernetes cluster on the first stage and then create Kubernetes objects on the second stage.

Answer (score 0):

For EKS provider using Terraform.

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

provider "kubernetes" {
  config_context = "aws-test-terraform"
}
```